# using variable defintions with blogger from scratch

Tags: html, xml, blogger

I almost began from 0 with my new template, but once I add a variable definition and use it under the skin tag, an error shows up and I don't understand why?

This is the code here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
  &lt;head&gt;
  <title>
    <data:blog.pageTitle/>
  </title>
  <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
  <b:include data='blog' name='google-analytics'/>
  <b:skin>
    <![CDATA[
/* --------------------------------------------
Blogger Template Style
Name:     
Designer: 
URL:      
----------------------------------------------- */
/* Variable definitions
=========================
<Variable name="mb.color" description="Main Background Color" type="color" default="#ffffff" value="#f1f1f1"/>
*/
/* Content
========================= */
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:$(mb.color);
}
]]>
  </b:skin>
  &lt;/head&gt;&lt;!-- 
  <head/>
  --&gt;
  <body>
    <b:section id='main'>
      <b:widget id='Blog1' locked='false' title='Articles' type='Blog' visible='true'>
        // code here
      </b:widget>
    </b:section>
    &lt;/body&gt;&lt;!-- 
  </body>
  --&gt;
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It allright, my template was corrupted i apply the default one and upload one more time my new one and the problem was gone! :)

Comment: Great. Being that the problem found is unlikely to be of help to others, you can delete the question. All the best.